# swift Property not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance, init

I have a class called badge that inherits from another class and I want the constructor method to tell the style of the notification.

**but I'm having this error:
Property 'self.notificationStyle' not initialized at super.init call**

> DefaultTableViewCell class

```
final public class DefaultTableViewCell: UITableViewCell

enum NotificationStyle {
        case numberedSquare, circle
    }
    
    var notificationStyle: NotificationStyle = .numberedSquare
```

my goal is whenever someone instantiates this Badge class, it will be necessary to inform the notificationStyle of it, being square or circular in this case.

how can i solve this?

> Badge class

```
@objc public class Badge: NotifyLabel

var notificationStyle: DefaultTableViewCell.NotificationStyle

init(frame: CGRect, notificationStyle: DefaultTableViewCell.NotificationStyle) {
        self.notificationStyle = notificationStyle
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup(notificationStyle: notificationStyle)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup(notificationStyle: notificationStyle)
    }
    
    init(notificationStyle: DefaultTableViewCell.NotificationStyle) {
        self.notificationStyle = notificationStyle
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setup(notificationStyle: notificationStyle)
    }

func configureBadgeNotificationStyle(notificationStyle: DefaultTableViewCell.NotificationStyle) {
        textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = Color.bostonRed.cgColor
        clipsToBounds = true
        textStyle = .label
        backgroundColor = Color.white
        
        switch notificationStyle {
        case .circle:
            layer.cornerRadius = 8
        default:
            layer.cornerRadius = 2
        }
    }
    
    private func setup(notificationStyle: DefaultTableViewCell.NotificationStyle) {
        configureBadgeNotificationStyle(notificationStyle: notificationStyle)
        configureAccessibility()
    }
```

> NotifyLabel class

```
public class NotifyLabel: UILabel

public init(textStyle: TextStyle) {
        self.textStyle = textStyle
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        applyTextStyle()
    }
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        applyTextStyle()
    }
    
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        applyTextStyle()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding a line to set `notificationStyle` to a default value in `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.notificationStyle = .numberedSquare //<-- Here
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup(notificationStyle: notificationStyle)
}
```

You have to do this because in your declaration of `notificationStyle`, there's no default value and it must have a value before calling `super.init`. In your other initializers, you set it based on the incoming arguments.

This is an initializer that it sounds like you're not using anyway, but it is required with `UIView`s that we implement this required initializer.

Comment: but if I instantiate My badge class like this

Badge(notificationStyle: .circle)

My badge going to squared

I need my badge is circle or squared based on notificationStyle passed in his init method

Comment: No, it wouldn’t. That’s a different initializer altogether. You’ve defined it and the code looks fine. The error is from an initializer that you aren’t using. Did you try the solution?

Comment: I forget an step, sorry it works fine!!
thanks! @jnpdx